# How to find a file in Unix using find command?

Tags: find

I have been trying to search for a file which contains a specific pattern. The pattern is itself in a variable tmpfl

```
echo $tmpfl --> ack_2*
```

Now to find for the file in the current working directory itself I have been trying to use

```
find . -name $tmpfl

find . -name ($tmpfl)
```

but none of them seem to work .
Though

```
find . -name ack_2*
```

works like a charm .

What is wrong in the approach ? It's simple variable substitution in Unix , right ? So what am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put "" around your variable.

```
find . -name "$tmpfl"
```

Comment: I don't think that quoting matter here. Double quotes is used only when variable contains whitespaces. BTW, `find -name $tmpfl` works for me.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk. No. double quote is used always. Leaving out the quotes is when you want the split+glob operator (nothing to do with spaces except for the split part if `$IFS` happens to contain space) to be invoked upon the expansion (in list contexts). In this case though,  `find . -name $tmpfl` with the default value of IFS and tmpl containing `act2_*` would be equally wrong as `find . -name act2_*` as that glob would (could) be expanded in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I have found there are certain situations (besides whitespace or unprintable characters) that require the double quotes around the `-name` parameter, regardless of whether the parameter is a variable or a hard-coded value.  Always good to get in the habit of using them.

Comment: Leaving a variable expansion unquoted in list contexts in POSIX shells is the split+glob operator. Situations where you actually want that are very rare (and here is definitely not one), so variable expansions should generally be quoted.